# Ubuntu 20.04 very slow

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, usb-installation, nvme

I am Windows user for quite a long time and wanted to try Ubuntu. With no experience of using any other OS than Windows, I started searching about Linux and found that Ubuntu is by far the most popular distro. Hence, my next search was how to install it alongside my Windows 10. After following step by step guide, I managed to install Ubuntu 20.04 using USB bootable disk on my Lenovo Legion Y520 laptop.

It is very capable laptop at least for Ubuntu, having Intel Core i5-7300hq, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB, 1TB HDD.

I later installed ADATA 256GB NVME M.2 SSD and installed Windows on it. The first problem I face while installing Ubuntu was that I didn't had an option to select my NVME SSD, the only option available was my HDD. Since I didn't had other option I went ahead with HDD installation.

The Installation went smooth though very slow, at least as compared to a Windows 10 installation. But I gave it a benefit of doubt since my Windows 10 is installed on NVME and this Ubuntu installation is done on mechanical HDD. I then changed my regional settings to US and it asked me to restart the PC.

From here onwards I started hating Ubuntu simply because it took around 5 minutes to restart. I thought that may be it is first time that is why it is taking time and therefore I decided to shutdown the PC so that I will power ON it again to see the difference.

Ubuntu refuse to power off and stuck at stopping disk. The had to hold power button to switch that off and immediately came here to ask you guys if I have done anything wrong which is causing Ubuntu to behave unusually.

Comment: Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to the Lenovo web site with your COMPLETE model #, and see if there's a newer BIOS available. Regarding the disk problem, in your BIOS, is the disk subsystem set to RAID/RST? Report back.

Comment: You figured it out yourself that the mechanical HDD is the big factor that is slowing down your OS. Try installing Ubuntu alongside Win10 on the same NVMe (by following steps in the answer already provided).

Answer (score 3):

@Zeeshan, solution is: install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 to the same SSD. But before installation of Ubuntu, safecopy / remove all your files from HDD to external drive and format you HDD to Fat32 (for both Linux and Windows). Then disconnect HDD power and data cables of HDD or delete HDD for a while. Change BIOS from Uefi to Legacy boot mode. Disable Windows fast startup. Now install Ubuntu. Ubuntu installation program will automatically ask for possibility for installation alonside Windows, accept it. After installation you have Grub2 boot menu for booting both Ubuntu and Win in the same SSD and both will boot quickly. Re-connect HDD cables or reinstall HDD. Re-boot to BIOS and add HDD to PC configuration. Use HDD as mass storage for both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with kernel 5.4.xy and higher you can format your flash drives also in exFAT format, but since exFAT is lacking support for journaling it is evidently not good for internal or external mass storages. Please see itsfoss.com/format-exfat-linux and digitalcitizen.life/what-is-exfat-why-useful

Comment: Why not have NTFS on HDD?

Comment: NTFS is also OK for HDD when these ntfs-3g driver features are be acknowledged  / handled: https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#rootfs.